Answering one's own questions
As you can see, I just asked a question about 升, 陞 and 昇. I spent some time checking various websites and found an answer which was fairly straightforward, so I answered my own question since others might also like to know what the difference is between these characters. Is this acceptable? I noticed that there is a function for answering one's own questions, but I'd still like to check if I'm doing the right thing.

This is a good question. I appreciate users getting interested in the site. 
Yes, you can answer your own question. Actually, if you see nobody else is answering or if your answer might be better than the existing ones, then you should! :)
This will be very helpful for future visitors, not to mention you'll gain reputation from both answer and question.
Please, note that when you accept your own answer, you won't get the +15 reputation. Only reputation from upvotes will still work.

Ok, got it! Thanks.

I often use this site or Stack Overflow as a way to record the results of research. My personal rule of thumb is that anything that takes me more than 15 minutes to search for gets recorded. If I found somebody else's question during the research, then I'll post my results as an answer, otherwise I'll post my own question with the answer.
I suspect that the process of writing up the question and answer helps me remember better, and I have often gone back to old answers to remind myself of the details. Perhaps that's a good topic for Hacking Chinese.

Yes, that's what I thought as well. I normally keep a record of all results in my Anki deck (I add comments to words and characters). However, it seems stupid not to share results if the question is likely to pop up for other learners and the answer wasn't trivial to find. Thanks for the suggestion!
